# Why my code doesn't run?

Tags: assembly

I'm trying my best to figure out why this code doesn't run. VS express 2010 announces "cannot find or open the PDB file", and "myname.exe has triggered a breakpoint".
Any help, please!

```
; This program computes 5!
.386
.model flat
.stack 4096
.data
factorial dword ?
.Code
_start:
mov eax , 5
mov ebx , 5
sub ebx , 1
mul ebx
sub ebx , 1
mul ebx
sub ebx , 1
mul ebx
sub ebx , 1
mul ebx
mov factorial , eax
public _start    
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has no end. There is no return statement at the end of your function. `end` is an instruction to the assembler, it does not generate any code. The assembler will fill the rest of the code segment with int3 instructions, exactly to provoke said breakpoint interrupt in case somebody tries to execute code outside a valid code block.

To fix your code, it would be best to create a stack frame around your function.